How to output a vector in C++ from the middle outwards
Is there a simple way to output the elements of a vector starting from the middle and moving outward towards the ends? I want to split a vector:
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

into two halves and read them out in alternating order: output the first part of the vector in reverse order and the latter part in forward order.
4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 1

In this case, the vector was split:
v1 = 1, 2, 3
v2 = 4, 5, 6

... then the output comes from incrementing v2, then decrementing v1, then incrementing v2, and so on.
My first thought was to make two new vectors, reverse the order of one, and then alternate reading them out. This works for small vectors, but is slow and becomes a memory hog for large vectors.
My next thought was a Custom Iterator that increments with an increasing amount and alternates sign. In the example, start at index 3, then decrement 1, increment 2, decrement 3, and so on, but then you have to be careful about how the iteration ends and that all elements have been reached.
Another thought was to imagine the vector as a ring and increment with alternating sign, a decreasing iterator and a modulo operator:
// MRE_middleOut.c
//
// Compile with: g++ -std=c++11 MRE_middleOut.c -o MRE_middleOut
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

inline int positive_modulo(int i, int n) {
    return (i % n + n) % n;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int N = strtol( argv[1], NULL, 10);
  vector<int> v;
  for ( int i=0; i<N; i++ )
    v.push_back( i+1 );
  int index = round( N / 2 );
  int sign = 1;
  printf( "%d, ", v[index] );
  for ( int stepSize=(N-1); stepSize>0; stepSize-- ) {
    index = positive_modulo( (index + sign*stepSize), N );
    sign *= -1;
    printf( "%d, ", v[index] );
  }
  printf( "\n" );
}


That gives the correct result, ...
$ ./MRE_middleOut 20
11, 10, 12, 9, 13, 8, 14, 7, 15, 6, 16, 5, 17, 4, 18, 3, 19, 2, 20, 1, 
$

... operates on the vector in-place (so it's fast), and ensures that all elements are read, but it is difficult to read and understand (plus you have to account for the weird way C/C++ handles modulo with negative inputs).
I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way to handle this.

Why is the output 3, 2, 4, 1, 5? There is no way to get that answer by splitting the vector in half once

You don't need to actually move the elements around to produce the output you want. You just need to iterate over them a certain way. Details are left as an exercise for the reader, as this sounds like homework.

@asimes My guess is, one is supposed to split the vector in half, then walk the second half forwards and the first half backwards, interleaved. At least, that is consistent with the example.

That was my guess too. Take the halfway point (rounded down) and then read right and left from there out to the ends, alternating sides beginning on the right. So a split {1,2} + {3,4,5} reads {3,4,5} interleaved with {2,1}.

there is a pattern of indices to access. If your vector is not too big, you can simply apply that pattern to access the elements (too big = it doesnt fit in the cache, then perhaps its worth to store the two halves)

maybe helpful or related implementation https://ideone.com/m4omSS

e.g. https://ideone.com/hIIWkv

How about this:
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

    size_t mid = vec.size() / 2;

    size_t left = mid - 1;
    size_t right = mid;
    bool printRight = true;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        size_t* ptrIndex = printRight ? &right : &left;
        std::cout << vec[*ptrIndex] << " ";
        *ptrIndex += printRight ? 1 : -1;
        printRight = !printRight;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

prints: 4 3 5 2 6 1
And if you really enjoy making your code unreadable and terse for no particular reason, the following is several lines shorter:
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << vec[vec.size() / 2 - (i % 2) + (1 - (2 * (i % 2))) * (i / 2)] << " ";
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
}


Clever use of the ptrIndex pointer to address the hi/lo index alternatively per iteration.

@DavidC.Rankin - if you like that, check out the other version I just updated it with.

Oh, now that's how to pack it all into an index. (i % 2 or i & 1 and switch ternary order). I like it! And ... a good thought provoking educational challenge for those making friends with the ternary operator :)

@DavidC.Rankin - updated to have no ternaries.  I'm not sure if I follow it anymore. :)

In the spirit of maximizing head scratches, you could add a version with 2 mutually recursive functions, one for the up and one for the down part, calling each other. Put those into some Macro and no one will ever be able to read it ;)

@BitTickler - my first example is would I would call a reasonable solution. The second one is just me having fun.

I accepted this as the answer, but the answers from Barmar and BitTickler should also work. The reason I asked the question was to see if I was missing an obvious, simple solution. As others have noted, the "pattern" is so simple, but the implementation is so "fiddly" (hat tip to @BitTickler!). The good thing is that any future readers now have several different approaches available to them from which they can pick.

@MarkBower My solution avoids having to think a lot. Especially about whether both ends are reached at the same loop step or if not, which one arrives first, depending on odd or even array sizes.


I was just wondering if there was a more elegant way to handle this.

Because of the odd vs even array length, it is a bit fiddly, no matter how you do it. The basic idea is:

Let n = length of array
let mid = n / 2
use 2 signed integer variables iup, idown
iup = mid
idown = mid -1
while (iup < n) or (idown >= 0)
when iup < n do print array[iup]
when idown >= 0 do print array[idown]
iup = iup + 1
idown = idown - 1
DONE

As it is probably your homework and there needs to be something left to do for you, I give you a sample implementation in another language ;)
(let ((arr (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6)))
  (loop
    with n = (length arr)
    with mid = (floor n 2)
    for iup = mid then (+ iup 1)
    for idown = (- mid 1) then (- idown 1)
    while (or (< iup n) (>= idown 0))
    when (< iup n)
      do (format t "~a " (aref arr iup))
    when (>= idown 0)
      do (format t "~a " (aref arr idown))))


The pattern of the indexes is: subtract 1, add 2, subtract 3, add 4, subtract 5, etc.
So you don't need any modular arithmetic. Just increase the increment by 1 each time, and alternate the sign. Stop when you get an index that's out of range for the vector.
for (int index = N/2, sign = 1, increment = 0; 
     index >= 0 && index < N; 
     index += sign * increment) {
    cout << v[index] << ", ";
    increment++;
    sign *= -1;
}
cout << '\n';

